# Can't add TemplateField to Datagrid

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio, drop-down-menu, datagrid

I am trying to add a DropDownList into the DataGrid so the location column can be easily changed. I am getting an error with TemplateField, itemtemplate, label and DropDownList. I get the build error:

> is not allowed within a
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridColumnCollection'.

```
 <asp:DataGrid runat="server" CssClass="tblResults" OnItemDataBound="dgList_ItemCreated" AllowSorting="true" OnSortCommand="dgTrailer_Sort" ID="dgTrailers" DataKeyField="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="TrailerOwner" HeaderText="Owner" SortExpression="TrailerOwner"></asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="TrailerMake" HeaderText="Trailer Make" SortExpression="TrailerMake"></asp:BoundColumn>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Trailer Location">
                        <itemtemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Location") %>' Visible = "false" />
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocation" runat="server">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                     </itemtemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Year" HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="Year"></asp:BoundColumn>

                    </Columns>
            </asp:DataGrid>
```

TemplateField, itemtemplate, label and DropDownList all have green lines under them and which means its not a known element.

Comment: Which is not allowed?

Comment: Which version of .net fx you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `TemplateColumn`, when it comes to DataGrid as it is inherited from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridColumn`.

TemplateField is inherited from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField`, which make sense with GridView.